# Typekit – find font details from embed code

Tags: fonts, embed, typekit

I inherited a website from a previous team which had a `Typekit` embed, but didn't come with access to the `Typekit` account or any of the font details. I needed to replicate the kit on my own account with the exact same kit details in order to keep the site working.

So how do you get the `Typekit` kit details simply from the embed code?

Answer (score 0):

All the info you need can be found in the inspector where you'll find a list of font families, followed by further details in the `window.Typekit.config` function.

`Chrome`: Go to Sources, and find use.typekit.js in the sidebar.

`Safari`: Go to Resources > Scripts and find use.typekit.js in the sidebar.

(`Safari v9.1` displays the code with white space, so it's easier to read the info)